# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy

I have this SQL Code. It just runs fine when i run this from the SQL Developer. 
I have a need to execute from my groovy script

```
sql.executeInsert("INSERT INTO s_status (C_DATE, sl_id, st_id, PARENT_st_id, STATUS, DETAILS, ACTIVE_IND) SELECT cd.cc_date, sl_id, st_id+1 st_id, st_id parent_st_id, 'CONFIRMED' status, 'SQL' details, 'Y' active_ind FROM s_status ss JOIN v_c_dates cd ON 1=1 WHERE (sl_id, st_id) IN (SELECT sl.sl_id, MAX(st_id) st_id FROM s_status ss JOIN stats sl ON ss.sl_id = sl.sl_id JOIN site si ON si.site_id = sl.site_id JOIN orders d ON d.ord_id = si.ord_id GROUP BY sl.sl_id ) and ss.active_ind = 'N' and ss.status = 'SENT'")
```

I see this error in my groovy console when i run this from groovy. Help me figuing the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO s_status (C_DATE, sl_id, st_id, PARENT_st_id, STATUS, DETAILS, ACTIVE_IND) 
SELECT cd.cc_date, sl_id, st_id+1, st_id, 'CONFIRMED', 
'SQL', 'Y'
FROM s_status ss JOIN v_c_dates cd ON 1=1 
WHERE (sl_id, st_id) IN 
(SELECT sl.sl_id, MAX(st_id) --use table alias before st_id
 FROM s_status ss JOIN stats sl ON ss.sl_id = sl.sl_id
 JOIN site si ON si.site_id = sl.site_id 
 JOIN orders d ON d.ord_id = si.ord_id 
 GROUP BY sl.sl_id) 
and ss.active_ind = 'N' and ss.status = 'SENT'
```

You don't need aliasing in the `select` statement. Modified your statement accordingly. You also need to look at the comment in the code where you need to use a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several cases where ORA-00933 was caused by case sensitivity.  Be sure the table and column name references match the schema.